# Javascript Line Break Textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a text area that I want to pre-populate with some specific text that includes line breaks.  I'm populating the area onLoad but I can't get the line breaks to work correctly.  Any advice on how to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: post code sample, data sample, environment and browser you're running. also give people credit for answers to your other questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to replace line breaks with newline characters: `\n`

Answer (score 8):

Just use the newline character: `\n`.

So, if you want the textarea to look like this:

> This is line 1
>   This is line 2

You would use a string like this:

```
"This is line 1\nThis is line 2";
```

See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/MzmBd/

Answer (score 1):

As stated multiple times, you need the `\n` character.

see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/XbALv/

```
document.getElementById("blah").value = 
"This" + "\n" +
"is some" + "\n" +
"text" + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

i had tried many ways to break a textarea into an array. used this method, it might not be the best.

using .split('\n') does not remove the break and it will create whitespace or break when insert into database. therefore, i replace it with

textarea content:

12345
6789

---

```
a = a.replace(/\n|\r\n|\r/g, "<br>");

var stringArray = a.split('<br>');

for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
var myString = stringArray[i];
myString = myString.replace('<br>', "");

response.write(myString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace like this:

```
str.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '\\\n') %>';
```

Answer (score 0):

break a textarea into an array

**textarea content:**
underscore_case
first_name
Some_Variable
calculate_AGE
delayed_departure

```
   const variableCase = function (variable) {
        const variableSplit = variable.split('\n');
        const spaceRemoved = [];

        for (const removeSpace of variableSplit) {
          const RST = removeSpace.trim();
          spaceRemoved.push(RST);
        }

        console.log(spaceRemoved); // output: ["underscore_case", "first_name", "Some_Variable", "calculate_AGE", "delayed_departure"]
      };
```