# If a parameter of event handler contains certain characters, JavaScript does not execute properly

Tags: javascript, php

php:

```
$str1 = "AAA\r\nBBBB\\CCC";
echo"<textarea id='aa1' onfocus='erase(\"".$str1."\", \"aa1\");'></textarea>";
$str2 = "AAABBBB\\CCC";
echo"<textarea id='aa2' onfocus='erase(\"".$str2."\", \"aa2\");'></textarea>";
$str3 = "AAABBBB\CCC";
echo"<textarea id='aa3' onfocus='erase(\"".$str3."\", \"aa3\");'></textarea>";
$str4 = "AAABBBBCCC";
echo"<textarea id='aa4' onfocus='erase(\"".$str4."\", \"aa4\");'></textarea>";
```

javascript:

```
function erase(str, id)
{
    alert("good");
    var field = document.getElementById(id);
    if(field.value == str)
    {
        field.value = '';
    }
}
```

If I click on `textarea id='aa1'`, nothing happens.

If I click on `textarea id='aa2'` or `textarea id='aa3'`, 'good' is printed but nothing happens to `field.value`.

If I click on `textarea id='aa4'`, 'good' is printed and `field.value` is ''.

I want a string like `AAA\r\nBBBB\\CCC` to work like `textarea id='aa4`.

How can I do that?

I read the post below but it does not seem to help my situation:

[Javascript parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843474/javascript-parameter)

[Javascript Line Break Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793923/javascript-line-break-textarea)

---

**update:**

I've replaced `$str1` with `json_encode($str1)`, So `alert();` works fine now. (Thanks to Jordan Running.)

But the `field.value` part still does not work.

code refactoring is too hard in my situation... Is there any way to handle the `field.value` problem without code refactoring?

If quotes corrupt my HTML, I can putting `$str1` in `htmlspecialchars()` and displaying it in `<textarea>`.

Comment: JS string cannot handle newlines. You can JSON encode them if you need the crlf

Comment: Check the error console?

Comment: String building JS from another language is a bad idea. Consider researching unobtrusive JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking it's a bad idea to use string concatenation to build JavaScript. Your PHP code produces the following HTML:

```html
<textarea id='aa1' onfocus='erase("AAA
BBBB\CCC", "aa1");'></textarea>
```

That's valid HTML, but the code in your `onfocus` attribute is *not* valid JavaScript. In JavaScript, you can't have a line break in the middle of a string literal. You can have a line break in a template literal (i.e. `` `one of these` ``), but that's not the right solution here.

## A quick but short-sighted fix

When you need to "inject" some data into a block of JavaScript, you should always use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```php
$str1 = "AAA\r\nBBBB\\CCC";
echo "<textarea id='aa1' onfocus='erase(" . json_encode($str1) . ", \"aa1\");'></textarea>";
```

Make careful note of the quotation marks above. Because `json_encode` wraps strings in quotation marks, you don't need additional quotes around `. json_encode($str1) .`.

This will produce the following HTML:

```html
<textarea id='aa1' onfocus='erase("AAA\r\nBBBB\\CCC", "aa1");'></textarea>
```

...whose `onfocus` handler works correctly, as you can see in this snippet:

```js
function erase(...args) { console.log('erase called with', args); }
```

```html
<textarea id='aa1' onfocus='erase("AAA\r\nBBBB\\CCC", "aa1");'></textarea>
```

## A better way

The above is still fragile. What if your data has a `'` in it? That'll break your HTML. The correct solution is to move your data out of the HTML entirely. Consider if you refactored your code to look something like this:

```
<textarea id="aa1"></textarea>
<textarea id="aa2"></textarea>
<textarea id="aa3"></textarea>
<textarea id="aa4"></textarea>
<?php
  $erase_map = [
    'aa1' => "AAA\r\nBBBB\\CCC",
    'aa2' => "AAABBBB\\CCC",
    'aa3' => "AAABBBB\CCC",
    'aa4' => "AAABBBBCCC",
  ];
?>
<script>
  const ERASE_MAP = <?php echo json_encode($erase_map); ?>;

  function erase(event) {
    if (event.target.value == ERASE_MAP[event.target.id]) {
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }
  document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(textarea => textarea.addEventListener('focus', erase));
</script>
```

In the above code, all of the data is in one place—a single associative array—instead of scattered around your HTML. It generates HTML code with a `<script>` tag into which the data is injected as a JSON object and assigned to a JavaScript variable:

```html
<textarea id="aa1"></textarea>
<textarea id="aa2"></textarea>
<textarea id="aa3"></textarea>
<textarea id="aa4"></textarea>
<script>
  const ERASE_MAP = {"aa1":"AAA\r\nBBBB\\CCC","aa2":"AAABBBB\\CCC","aa3":"AAABBBB\\CCC","aa4":"AAABBBBCCC"};
  
  function erase(event) {
    if (event.target.value == ERASE_MAP[event.target.id]) {
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }
  document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(textarea => textarea.addEventListener('focus', erase));
</script>
```

Comment: If quotes corrupt my HTML, I can putting `$str1` in `htmlspecialchars()` and displaying it in `<textarea>`.  Is there any way to handle the `field.value` problem without code refactoring? @JordanRunning

Comment: @Saturn It's hard to help you solve a problem if you don't explain what it is. However, I have a feeling the issue is that you're comparing `AAA\r\nBBBB…` to `AAA\nBBBB…`. See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area If you're still having trouble, post a new question.